# Getting the grand total of a report via ReportResults in apex

Tags: apex, reports-api

I am attempting to get the grand total of a report via apex. Currently the only way I can see of how to do this is by iterating through each summary section on the report (as shown in the code below). In this case I have summarized by attr1, however I want to have a report with no summaries (beyond the grand total). Is there a way to access the grand total of the report without having to have summary groupings on the report?

```
public static void generateSummaryData(){

    List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where DeveloperName = 'health_data_test'];
    String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

    Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);  

    Reports.Dimension dim = results.getGroupingsDown();

    //Store the count of the total records in the report
    Integer countOfRecords = 0;

    for(Reports.GroupingValue groupingVal : dim.getGroupings()){

        String factMapKey = groupingVal.getKey() + '!T';

        Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails)results.getFactMap().get(factMapKey);

        Reports.SummaryValue sumVal = factDetails.getAggregates()[0];
        countOfRecords += Integer.valueOf(sumVal.getLabel());

    }

   //Count of the total records in the report
   System.debug('countOfRecords: ' + countOfRecords);

}
```

Below is the report that I am gathering the data off of
[image]

Comment: Is `T!T` populated?

Comment: My apologies, I have not worked with this API much. What does T!T represent.

Comment: Neither have I, but I noticed it was in the docs. I'm not sure if it's populated for a summary report though. T!T is supposed to represent the grand total for the report.

Comment: I was able to find how to do it! Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was eventually able to build a method that will capture the grand total from a report. Essentially you create a top level factmap of the report and then iterate through to the last aggregate, which is the grandtotal(RowCount). I was also able to determine that you can grab data for summed columns in the report.  Below is my code:

```
    public static Decimal getGrandTotal(String reportName){

    // Get the report ID
    List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where DeveloperName = 'reportName'];
    String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

    // Run a report synchronously
    Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);

    //get the reports factmap fro the report ID and select the top level fact map - (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_fact_map.htm)
    Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails1 = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails)results.getFactMap().get('T!T');

    //get the aggregate values in the report, this includes the RowCount (Grand Total) and any columns that have been summarized.
    List<Reports.SummaryValue> profileCounts = factDetails1.getAggregates();

    //The row count will be the last aggregate in the list, any summaries will come first and you can loop through them in the method below.
    Decimal grandTotal =  (Decimal)profileCounts.get(profileCounts.size()-1).getValue();

    System.debug('Record count: ' + grandTotal);


    //Debug testing 
    /*
    System.debug('profileCounts: ' + profileCounts.get(profileCounts.size()-1).getValue());

    //loop through all the top level aggregates  and print their values 
    for(Reports.SummaryValue sumVal : factDetails1.getAggregates()){
            System.debug('Summary Label: ' + sumVal.getLabel() + 'Value: ' + sumVal.getValue() );  
    }
    */

    return grandTotal;
}
```

Resources: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_fact_map.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportfactwithdetails.htm